# Change of variable to show $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, problem-solving, change-of-variable

Which **change of variable** can be used to show
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
(direct integration isn't allowed, must use change of variable)

Comment: What change of variable would guess could change $(0,1)$ to $(1,\infty)$ ?

Comment: Hint: $[0, \infty) = [0, 1] \cup [1, \infty)$ and the change of variable happens on the unbounded interval.

Comment: @NinadMunshi were you also thinking of the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ (provided below by J.G.) are there different substitutions that would also work?

Comment: Well no, try the substitution and you will see why it is special.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I can see this substitution works, but is there a reason that no other substitutions would also work?

Comment: @NinadMunshi is right. In fact, integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)dx}{1+x^2}$ are often special because of this substitution.

Comment: @J.G. Can you elaborate? Why is $u=\frac{1}{x}$ the only one that works?

Comment: @c0123 Well, if $\int_0^1\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\int_0^1\frac{dv}{1+v^2}$, what do you expect would work beside $v=u=1/x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required change of variable is
$$x = \tan ( 2\tan^{-1}y),\>\>\>\>\> dx = \sec^2(2\tan^{-1}y)\frac{2dy}{1+y^2}
$$
which leads to
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}
= \int_0^{1}\frac{\sec^2(2\tan^{-1}y)}{1+ \tan^2( 2\tan^{-1}y)}
\frac{2dy}{1+y^2}
=2\int_0^1\frac{dy}{1+y^2}$$

Comment: what motivated you to consider this substitution?

Comment: @c0123 - the specific form of the integrands, i.e. $\frac1{1+x^2}=(\tan^{-1}x)’$

Comment: yes but how did you know to put the 2 like that in $x=tan(2tan^{-1}y)$

Comment: @c0123 - that is due to the limits. i.e. $$\tan^{-1}x\bigg|_0^\infty = 2\tan^{-1}y\bigg|_0^1$$

Answer (score 1):

To show the equivalent result $\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$, use $x\mapsto1/x$.

Harder version, requiring no rewriting of the problem in an equivalent form: to show $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_0^1\frac{2dx}{1+x^2}$, use $x\mapsto\exp(-|\ln x|)$.

Comment: Your 'harder version' is quite interesting, what motivated you to think about this, how would this method generalize?

Comment: @c0123 All I did was take the easy method, then "glue" the two pieces together to do the same thing without having to subtract the $\int_0^1$ first.

Comment: @c0123 Exactly: if we leave $x$ as-is left of $1$ but reciprocate above $1$, we fold over to $(0,\,1)$. More generally $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^1(f(x)+f(1/x)/x^2)dx$.

Comment: Your gluing method is very neat, how do you come up with that? More generally, if you want to do one transform on (0,a) and a different one on $(a,\infty)$ how do you write that as one expression like you did above?

Comment: @c0123 You need to find a transformation that converts an $\int_a^\infty dx_\text{old}$ to $\int_0^a dx_\text{new}$ (never mind for the moment how the integrand transforms), e.g. $x_\text{new}=a^2/x_\text{old}$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative

$$\tan(u) ~=~ x ~\implies~$$

$$\text{[informally]}
~\sec^2(u)du ~=~ dx ~~~\text{and}$$

$$~\frac{1}{1 + x^2} ~=~ \cos^2(u) ~\implies $$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^{\pi/2} du
= 2\int_0^{\pi/4} du = 2\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
now:
$$I_1=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$u=\frac1x,du=-1/x^2dx\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{1}{u^2}du$$
$$I_1=-\int_1^0\frac{1}{1+(1/u)^2}\frac{du}{u^2}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2}$$
$$\therefore I=2\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$